# How does this expression simplify to the expression given by my teacher (Bernoulli trial)

Tags: probability

I am studying computer science in university and we are currently looking at statistics and probability as part of our mathematics module. The current problem i am having is that when evaluating this examination question:

"what are the chances of getting four sixes in six tosses of a fair die?"

I am using the Bernoulli trials for this question, as that is the way the teacher wants us to tackle the problem.

My current workings out are as follows:

n = 6      k = 4      p = 1/6 (fair die so each number is 1/6 chance of occurring)

so:  f(4) = (6 4) (1/6)^4 (1 - 1/6)^(6-4)

where (n k) = n! / k!(n-k)!  therefore :(6 4) =  6! / k!(6-4)!  = 6!/4!2!

so using the above:

6!/4!(6-4)! (1/6)^4 (5/6)^2

I have managed to get this far, but then in the revision notes provides by my teacher, she continues to go on to the following simplification.

From this point on i have no idea how this happens:

6!/4!(6-4)! (1/6)^4 (5/6)^2

= 6x5/2 = (1/6^4) (25/6^2) Where does the 6x5 come from?

=  125/(2 × 6^5) where does 6^5 come from, shouldn't it be 6^4 x 6^2 = 6^6?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Chris.

Comment: Just look again at it and use that $6!/4!=6\cdot 5$.

Comment: First we look at your $\frac{6!}{4!2!}$. The top is $(6)(5)(4!)$. So our ratio is
$\frac{(6)(5)(4!)}{4!2!}$. The $4!$ at top and bottom cancel. And later the $6$ on top cancels with one of the $6$ at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6!/4!(6-4)! (1/6)^4 (5/6)^2 will be
$$\frac{6!}{4!(6-4)!}\cdot\left(\frac 16\right)^4\cdot\left(\frac 56\right)^2=\frac{6\cdot 5}{2\cdot 1}\cdot\frac{5^2}{6\cdot 6^5}=\frac{5^3}{2\cdot6^5}=\frac{125}{2\cdot 6^5}.$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: ye sorry, i didn't know how to format the maths so it was more readable. just a quick question, where does the 15 come from?

Comment: I edited a bit. Now clear? $6!/(4!\cdot 2!)=6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1/(4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdot 1).$

Comment: got it! thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!